# Navigate to search result Flutter Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-places-api, google-geolocation

I have a SearchMapPlaceWidget that suggests me places based on my search keyword. I want to animate the camera to the suggested place I tap on. How do I do that?

Here's the SearchMapPlaceWidget that I used from search_map_place package in Flutter.

```
SearchMapPlaceWidget(
  apiKey: myApiKey,
  onSearch: (Place place) async {
    try{
      final geolocation = await place.geolocation;
      print(geolocation);
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

From official example https://pub.dev/packages/search_map_place#example 
You can use `GoogleMapController` and call `animateCamera`

```
return SearchMapPlaceWidget(
    apiKey: YOUR_API_KEY,
    // The language of the autocompletion
    language: 'en',
    // The position used to give better recomendations. In this case we are using the user position
    location: userPosition.coordinates,
    radius: 30000,
    onSelected: (Place place) async {
        final geolocation = await place.geolocation;

        // Will animate the GoogleMap camera, taking us to the selected position with an appropriate zoom
        final GoogleMapController controller = await _mapController.future;
        controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(geolocation.coordinates));
        controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(geolocation.bounds, 0));
    },
);
```

From Official example have all the code you need 
Screen with map and search box on top. When the user selects a place through autocompletion,the screen is moved to the selected location 
https://github.com/Bernardi23/search_map_place/blob/master/example/advanced_example.dart 
You can directly run this example

It's too long, I just paste `_mapController` part

```
Completer<GoogleMapController> _mapController = Completer();
...
GoogleMap(
            ...
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
              _mapController.complete(controller);
...
final GoogleMapController controller = await _mapController.future;
```

Comment: In this snippet, what's the _mapController? Because I have a GoogleMapController instance, called _controller which I passed there, but it doesn't have a future.